# Integral of $\exp$ over the unit ball

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I would like to know if the following integral has a closed form. Let $B(0,r)$ be the euclidean ball in $\mathbb{R}^d$.

I am intered in $$\int_{B(0,r)}\exp(-i \langle x,\xi\rangle) dx_1\ldots dx_d$$
where $\langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle$ is the standard dot product. 
(I will assume that $\xi_i\ne 0$ for all $i$)

For $d=1$ it's easy but even for $d=2$ i am stuck. Using polar coordinate I get $$\int_{[0,\infty)\times (0,2\pi)} \exp(-ir(\cos\theta\xi_1 +sin\theta\xi_2))rdrd\theta.$$

Not helpful...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Taylor Series**

Using $\Omega_{n-1}=\frac{\pi^{\frac{n-1}2}}{\Gamma\left(\frac{n+1}2\right)}$, we can compute the Taylor series of the integral for any $n$:
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{|x|\le R}e^{-ix\cdot\xi}\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\Omega_{n-1}R^n\int_{-1}^1\cos(|\xi|Rt)\,\left(1-t^2\right)^{\frac{n-1}2}\mathrm{d}t\tag1\\
&=\Omega_{n-1}R^n\int_0^1\cos\left(|\xi|R\sqrt{t}\right)\,(1-t)^{\frac{n-1}2}t^{-1/2}\,\mathrm{d}t\tag2\\
&=\Omega_{n-1}R^n\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k\frac{|\xi|^{2k}R^{2k}}{(2k)!}\frac{\Gamma\!\left(\frac{n+1}2\right)\Gamma\!\left(k+\frac12\right)}{\Gamma\!\left(\frac{n}2+k+1\right)}\tag3\\
&=\pi^{\frac{n-1}2}R^n\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k\frac{|\xi|^{2k}R^{2k}}{(2k)!}\frac{\Gamma\!\left(k+\frac12\right)}{\Gamma\!\left(\frac{n}2+k+1\right)}\tag4\\
&=\pi^{\frac{n}2}R^n\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k\frac{|\xi|^{2k}R^{2k}}{4^kk!\,\Gamma\!\left(\frac{n}2+k+1\right)}\tag5\\
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: write as an integral in slices $\perp\!\xi$ of radius $R\sqrt{1-t^2}$ where $x\cdot\xi=|\xi|Rt$
$(2)$: apply symmetry to restrict to $[0,1]$ and substitute $t\mapsto\sqrt{t}$
$(3)$: use the Taylor series for cosine and the [Beta Integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function)
$(4)$: apply the value of $\Omega_{n-1}$
$(5)$: $\frac{\Gamma\left(k+\frac12\right)}{(2k)!}=\frac{\sqrt\pi}{4^kk!}$

As a check, note that for $\xi=0$, the sum is
$$
\frac{\pi^{n/2}}{\Gamma(n/2+1)}R^n=\Omega_nR^n\tag6
$$
which is the volume of a sphere of radius $R$.

---

**Closed Form**

Applying the series expansion for the [Bessel Function of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Bessel_functions_of_the_first_kind:_J%CE%B1)
$$
J_\alpha(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{k!\,\Gamma(k+\alpha+1)}\left(\frac{x}2\right)^{2k+\alpha}\tag7
$$
to $(5)$ yields
$$
\int_{|x|\le R}e^{-ix\cdot\xi}\,\mathrm{d}x
=\left(\frac{2\pi R}{|\xi|}\right)^{n/2}J_{n/2}\!\left(|\xi|R\right)\tag8
$$

Answer (score 5):

Use $n$-dimensional spherical coordinates and choose the polar axis to be parallel to $\xi$. Then the integral is
$$
\int_{\Omega} \int_0^R\int_0^\pi\exp(-i|\xi| r\cos\theta)r^{n-1}\sin^{n-2}\theta\,dr\,d\theta\,d^{n-2}\Omega,
$$
where $d^{n-2}\Omega$ represents the integral over all other spherical angles. This has the same value as the surface area of the unit sphere in $n-1$ dimensions, given by $2\pi^{(n-1)/2}/\Gamma[(n-1)/2]$. So the integral is given by
$$
\frac{2\pi^{(n-1)/2}}{\Gamma[(n-1)/2]}\int_0^R\int_0^\pi\exp(-i|\xi| r\cos\theta)r^{n-1}\sin^{n-2}\theta d\theta\,dr.
$$
Applying some substitutions gives
\begin{multline}
 \frac{2\pi^{(n-1)/2}}{\Gamma[(n-1)/2]}\int_0^R\int_0^\pi\exp(-i|\xi| r\cos\theta)r^{n-1}\sin^{n-2}\theta d\theta\,dr 
\\= \frac{2\pi^{(n-1)/2}}{|\xi|^n\Gamma[(n-1)/2]}\int_0^{R|\xi|} u^{n-1}\int_{-1}^1 \exp(-iu\zeta)(1-\zeta^2)^{(n-3)/2} d\zeta\,du.
\\ = \frac{(2\pi)^{n/2}}{|\xi|^n}\int_0^{R|\xi|}u^{n/2}J_{n/2-1}(u)du = \left(\frac{2\pi R}{|\xi|}\right)^{n/2}J_{n/2}(R|\xi|),
\end{multline}
where $J_\nu$ is the Bessel J function and I used [these](http://functions.wolfram.com/Bessel-TypeFunctions/BesselJ/07/01/01/0001/) [two](http://functions.wolfram.com/Bessel-TypeFunctions/BesselJ/20/01/02/0005/) Bessel function identities to simplify the integral.

In conclusion, 
$$
\int_{B_n(0,R)} \exp(-i\xi\cdot\mathbf{x})d^n\mathbf{x} = \left(\frac{2\pi R}{|\xi|}\right)^{n/2}J_{n/2}(R|\xi|),
$$

Comment: Yep.  The core insight is to rotate coordinates to be parallel to ${\bf \xi}$, where the integration is far more straightforward and yields Bessel functions.  (+1).

Comment: That's great. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @TTL The dot product of two vectors is the product of their magnitudes and the cosine of the angle between them. By definition, in $n$-dimensional spherical coordinates, $\theta$ is the angle between $\mathbf{x}$ and the polar axis. Since the direction of the polar axis can be chosen arbitrarily, we choose it to be parallel to $\xi$, so that $\theta$ is the angle between $\xi$ and $\mathbf{x}$. That means $\xi\cdot\mathbf{x} = |\xi|r\cos\theta$.

Comment: @eyeballfrog do you know if it's easy to derive the second identity using the first identity? That is, if I take the first identity to be the definition of Bessel function, can I get the derivative identity from there without much hassle? I tried but it gets messy really quickly for me.

Answer (score 2):

I guess, I have an idea.
You can use central symmetry of the problem and rotate your coordinate system.
Any rotation should have no impact on the integral.
Let me take [Spherical coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere#Spherical_coordinates)
$$
\begin{align}
x_1 &= r \cos(\varphi_1) \\
x_2 &= r \sin(\varphi_1) \cos(\varphi_2) \\
x_3 &= r \sin(\varphi_1) \sin(\varphi_2) \cos(\varphi_3) \\
    &\vdots\\
x_{n-1} &= r \sin(\varphi_1) \cdots \sin(\varphi_{n-2}) \cos(\varphi_{n-1}) \\
x_n &= r \sin(\varphi_1) \cdots \sin(\varphi_{n-2}) \sin(\varphi_{n-1}),
\end{align}
$$
and rotate everything so that $\vec{\xi}$ coincides with the axis to which I measure $\varphi_1$.
In this case your integral can be written as
$$
\int_{\varphi_{n-1}=0}^{2\pi} \int_{\varphi_{n-2}=0}^\pi \cdots \int_{\varphi_1=0}^\pi\int_{r=0}^R
e^{-ir\cos(\varphi_1)|\xi|}
r^{n-1}\sin^{n-2}(\varphi_1)\sin^{n-3}(\varphi_2)\cdots \sin(\varphi_{n-2})\,
dr\,d\varphi_1 \, d\varphi_2\cdots d\varphi_{n-1},
$$
or integrating most angles we get (hopefully, I didn't make a mistake)
$$
\frac{(\sqrt{\pi})^{n-3}}{\Gamma\left(\frac{n-1}{2}\right)}
\int_{\varphi_{n-1}=0}^{2\pi} \int_{r=0}^R
e^{-ir\cos(\varphi_1)|\xi|}
r^{n-1}\sin^{n-2}(\varphi_1)\,
dr\,d\varphi_1.
$$
The rest is up to you.
You may check for similar technique used in [Internal magnetic field distribution in plasmas](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/332646276_Internal_magnetic_field_distribution_in_plasmas) for 3D case.

Comment: Spherical symmetry is the key: if the quantity, you are interested in, is invariant with respect to some coordinate transformations, you can use them to simplify the problem, e.g. no calculations are needed, just say the words "I rotated the system so that...". Let me say it another way: consider a charge positioned at the axis origin. It creates field $1/r^2$, where $r$ is the distance to the charge. Does it care about our coordinates system? Not at all -- I can safely suppose that I measure this field being distance $r$ along any of the axis or whatever direction I find convenient.