# Integral of exp over the hypersphere

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, fourier-transform

I would like to know the closed form of the following integral in $\mathbb{R}^{d}$ if it exists.

It's
$$
f(\boldsymbol{\xi}, a) = \int_{B(\boldsymbol{0},R)} \exp{(-i (\boldsymbol{\xi} \cdot \boldsymbol{x} - |\boldsymbol{x}|a))} d\boldsymbol{x}
$$
where $a \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\boldsymbol{\xi} \in \mathbb{R}^{d}$.

In fact, when $a=0$, it has already been resolved: [Integral of exp over the unit ball](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3310890/integral-of-exp-over-the-unit-ball).

I feel this can't be written in closed form, but I appreciate your opinion.

Comment: @peterag you should check.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** In short, you have
\begin{align}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} e^{-i \xi\cdot x} f(|x|) dx
\end{align}
where $f(|x|)= \exp(i |x| a)\chi_{B(0, R)}$ is a radial function, i.e. Fourier transform a radial function.

Comment: Exactly! Is this kind of Fourier transformation often studied?

Comment: @Tsu-Fu_Samurai See  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2890531/an-integral-about-radial-function for reference.

Comment: Thank you for the useful information!